# What can we represent any integer $x$ by $x = p^k \cdot y (\mod p)$?

Tags: real-analysis, prime-numbers

This is a problem I encountered in real analysis.
Let $\mathbb{Z}$ be the set of integers and $p$ be a fixed prime number. Represent any $x ∈ Z$ as

$x = p^k · y$, where $y\not\equiv 0$ (mod $p$) ($k ∈ N∪{0},y ∈ Z$)

The problem then defines d(x,y) and asks us to show that d is a metric.
But I don't know why the above equation works. Like if $x=3$ and $p=2$ then what are k and y?

Comment: Obviously $x = 0$ can't be done so.

Comment: If $x = 3$ and $p = 2$ then $k = 0$ and $y = 2$.   $2 = 3^0\cdot 2$.

Comment: Oops typo in my comment.  If $x = 3$ and $p =2$ then $k =0$ and $y=3$.  So we have $3=2^0\cdot 3; 3\not\equiv 0 \pmod 2$.

Answer (score 1):

To see why this works, consider the prime factorisation of $x$. If it is of the form
$$ x = p^\alpha \cdot z$$ where $z$ does not divide $p$ (i.e. we put all the $p$ fators in $p^k$), then your $y=k$. The condition $y\not\equiv 0\ (mod\ p)$ is same as this divisibility condition mentioned above. If $p$ does not divide $x$, then you can set $k=0$ and $y=x$.

Answer (score 0):

We can't represent $x = 0$.

But if $x \ne 0$ it can be done.  Take the prime factorization of $x$.  Take the highest factor of $p$ that divides into $x$. Call that $k$. (If $p\not \mid x$ then $k=0$).  Let $y = \frac {x}{p^k}$.  As we have divided out all powers of $p$, we have $p \not \mid y$ and so $y \not \equiv 0 \pmod p$.

So you your example of $x=3$ and $p =2$ then $k = 0$ and $y = 3$ and $3 = 2^0\cdot 3$.

=====

> The problem then defines d(x,y) and asks us to show that d is a metric.

Just out of curiousity *HOW* does the problem define $d(x,y)$?

Comment: Thanks. Here's how $d(x,y)$ is defined:
\begin{align}
\text{Let } |x|_{(p)} =
        \begin{cases}
       p^{-k} , & \text{if $x \neq 0$} \\
        0, & \text{if $x=0$}
        \end{cases}
\end{align}
and $d(x,y)_{(p)} = |x-y|_{(p)}$

Comment: Yep.... p-adic norm.  Note $p^{-k}> 0$ for any $k$ so $|x-y|_p \ge 0$ and $|x-y|_p = 0\iff x-y=0\iff x=y$ so that's the first requirement of a metric. Not $p^k|m \iff p^k|-m$ so $|x-y|_p = |y-x|_p$ and that's the second. As always the essential one is the triangle inequality. But if $k_x$ is the highest power of $p$ that divides $x$ and $k_y$ the highest that divides $y$ then $k_{x-y}=\min(x,y)$ so $|x-y|=p^{-\min(x_k,x_y)}$.  Use that to prove the triangle inequality. Actually you can prove $|x-z|_p=\max(|x-y|_p,|y-z|_p)$. I like to call the the *isosceles* triangle inequality.